# How to handle try/exception block in python?

Tags: python

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break
    if num>largest:
            largest=num
    if smallest is None:
            smallest=num
    elif num<smallest:
            smallest=num  

    try :
       n=float(num)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
    continue    
    print num

print "Maximum", largest
print "Manimum", smallest
```

Comment: I am getting this as my output -> Invalid input
                                                    Maximum fred
                                                    Manimum 4

Comment: You should convert the raw_input `num` into a float before you start comparing it as a numerical value. Read the docs for [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for clarification..

Comment: I have updated it but still the same. I wanted print this as my output "Invalid input
Maximum is 7
Minimum is 4"

Comment: Please tell us what is wrong with your code and what you are trying to achieve in the question so that we are more able to help you. @useer1991

Comment: when I enter string value need to print "invalid input" and after terminating the loop need to show min and max value

Comment: Can you edit the question and update the code with the changes you mentioned, so we know what your current code looks like. @useer1991

Comment: I guess moving the `try` block before the update of `largest` and `smallest` may be a big step towards our unknown objective...

Answer (score 0):

Combining question text and comments, I assume that you wonder why the program does output erroneous input as `largest`. The answer to this is that you should move the `try` block checking your input right before the update of `largest` and `smallest`. Also it might be helpful to not use another variable `n` for the result of the conversion, but try `num = float(num)` after checking `num` for `"done"`.

*(As this is obviously homework, I will not post the "solution", but leave it with the hints.)*

Comment: @useer1991 Welcome. Feel free to accept the answer ;)